# Confused about String and Array of Char

Tags: arrays, string, char

How come it won't output things properly unless the string's size/length is at least 9 characters? Am I missing something?

Don't mind the implementation since I'm only after the output with this kind of logic.

```
const string numRow = "`1234567890-=";
const string firstRow = "QWERTYUIOP[]\\";
const string secondRow = "ASDFGHJKL;'";
const string thirdRow = "ZXCVBNM,./";

int main()
{
    while( 1 ) {
    string input;
    cout << "String: ";
    getline( cin, input, '\n');

    int len = input.length();
    cout << "Length of input: " << len << endl;
    char arr[ len ];

    // INITIALIZATION
    for( int i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
        if( i == len-1 )
            arr[i] = '\0';
        else
            arr[i] = ' ';
    }

    // CHECK NUMBER ROW OF THE KEYBOARD
    for( int i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
        for( int j = 0; j < len; j++ ) {
            if( numRow[ j ] != '`' && numRow[ j ] == input[i] ) {
                arr[i] = numRow[ j-1 ];
                break;
            }
            else if( numRow[ 0 ] == input[ i ] ) {
                arr[i] = numRow[ 0 ];
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    // SAME CONCEPT FOR THE REST OF THE CODE, CHECK FIRST/SECOND/THIRD 
    ROW OF THE KEYBOARD AND OUTPUT IT
}
```

Comment: You might want to reformat your question, as it is quite unclear -- what is the purpose of your snippet ? What is the expected output, versus the actual output ? We need more information that "it won't output things properly"

Comment: sorry bout that, it's a WERTYU problem. It's somewhat like, if the user inputs a "W", the output is "Q". Input instead the one at the left of that letter unless it's "`,Q,A,Z".

So a sentence like
O S, GOMR YPFSU/ is equivalent to I AM FINE TODAY.

Comment: "Output" instead the one at the left.. my bad

Answer (score 0):

The bounds of your inner loop (with the `j` variable) are wrong. You used `len`, the length of the input string. As a result you won't check the full numRow array on short inputs and have invalid (out of bounds) accesses on long inputs. Do something like this:

```
...
int numRowLen = numRow.length();
for (int j = 0; j < numRowLen; j++) {
...
```

Comment: Hmm, I believe .size() or .length() is better than strlen in many ways since it runs on O(1) compared to Θ(n). And the point of this program is to convert the given string, let's say O S, GOMR YPFSU/, into I AM FINE TODAY by outputting the left side of each inputted letter. I don't see any problem with the J variable since I need to check each letter of the input string and break when some conditions are met.

Comment: Tried strlen, didn't help at all.

Comment: @ZeferiniX Sorry, I tought that `numRow` was a plain C array. That mistake is fixed now. Anyway, you use `j` to index `numRow`, so `j` must be in the range `[0, numRow.length()-1]`.